# Right way to learn Shri Ramcharitmanas in Awadhi for someone who does not know Awadhi

Tags: scripture, ramayana, manuscripts, ramcharitmanas, tulsidas

I want to read and understand Shri Ramchatrimanas in its original Awadhi language and quite serious about it, tried multiple time but not able to.I can read Hindi but find it difficult to read/understand and pronounce Awadhi language. I have read the english translation.I am unable to find any online resources as well.

Can someone please suggest me what would be the right approach to do this.Is there any online or offline course/study group etc which will help me here?

Many Thanks